# How to check "isEmpty()" in Gson JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, gson

I used the Google Gson API to construct JSON. When I initialized a JsonObject with:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
```

and print it out, it was in fact `{}`.

I tried to exclude the "empty" JSON, i.e. the `{}` ones that were not added any properties. But I could not find a method resembling `isEmpty()` in the Gson API.

How can I find out the "empty" JSON with Gson API?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`JsonObject#entrySet()`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#entrySet--) to get the JSON object's set of name/value pairs (its members). That returns a `Set` which has the traditional `isEmpty()` method you're looking for.

For example,

```
JsonObject jsonObject = ...;
Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> members = jsonObject.entrySet();
if (members.isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Its more correct to use the *Set.isEmpty()* for this purpose

```
if (jsonObject.entrySet().isEmpty()) {

}
```